# Is it possible to bind dependencies to interceptor in TestNG?

Tags: java, testng, guice

```
public class AbstractTest implements ITestListener {

    @Inject
    protected MobConfiguration mob;
    
    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

When I tried to inject dependencies in the listener class, it always returns `null`.
Is there any possible ways to handle DI in listener or interceptor implementer classes?

Comment: _How_ did you attempt to inject the dependencies?

Comment: binder.bind(xxx.class).to(yyy.class);

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully tried [this approach](http://biggerwrench.blogspot.de/2014/02/testng-using-guice-for-dependency.html) (using a factory, code example at the end of this answer). There is one addition to care for, if you use groups annotations, the thereby discrimination (as in line 126 in code for TestDIFactory.java - [there again](http://biggerwrench.blogspot.de/2014/02/testng-using-guice-for-dependency.html)) seems to work reliable only if you use a testng.xml file.

Otherwise with annotation parameters only the default case ([l. 130, TestDIFactory.java](http://biggerwrench.blogspot.de/2014/02/testng-using-guice-for-dependency.html)) seems to get active. One can easily check that by adding `if(context.getIncludedGroups().length == 0) throw new NullPointerException("no groups found");` after [l. 122, TestDIFactory.java](http://biggerwrench.blogspot.de/2014/02/testng-using-guice-for-dependency.html)

If you need the `implements ITestListener` explicitly it should be easy to modify the `public void onStart(ITestContext context)` method accordingly.

```
@Guice(moduleFactory = TestDIFactory.class)
public class YourTestClass {
 @Inject protected MobConfiguration mob;

 @Test(groups = {"unit"})
 public void yourtest() {}
}
```

EDIT:
I have proven the factory approach problematic in one case:
If the modules provided by the factory share bindings meaning one object bound in module A is also bound in another module B but you request a combined module which installs / calls configure on A and B and then is returned by the factory. You run into a high change to get `InstantiationException`s. So rule of thumb for me: factories only when only one module per test is needed. In other cases I use i. e. `@Guice(modules = {TestDIFactory.A.class, TestDIFactory.B.class})` assumed given A and B public access though.

Answer (score 0):

While it will be possible in version **7.5.0**, in the **7.4.0** you can just:

```
@Override
public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
    final Injector parentInjector = context.getSuite().getParentInjector();
    final YourGuiceModule module = parentInjector.getInstance(YourGuiceModule.class);
    final MobConfiguration mob = parentInjector.createChildInjector(module).getInstance(MobConfiguration.class);
    
    mob.useIt();
}
```

This is valid if you bind the module on the test, if you bind it on the parent module you can just do a:

```
context.getSuite().getParentInjector().getInstance(MobConfiguration.class);
```