# How to use injection in Test NG test listener

Tags: java, dependency-injection, testng, cdi

I have a Test NG listener class, that is invoked every time a test fails:

```
public class MyListener implements ITestListener {

@Inject
private MyBean myBean;

@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    myBean.logDetails();
    // log certain information about the failure, 
    // using the injected object.
}
}
```

When a test fails, the method is called, this part works fine.

The problem is the object isn't injected - it's just null. I have checked everything, and the usual conditions for CDI working are all ok. 
The class has an empty constructor, and I am not calling new() on it anywhere.

Is there any way to get the object injected?

I have looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825372/is-it-possible-to-bind-dependencies-to-interceptor-in-testng) but I can't see how to do CDI in the test listener.
I've also tried annotating the listener class as a TestNG test, and also making the listener a subclass of a guice factory class, but no luck and I'm a bit lost as to how to do it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, TestNG doesn't allow injection (with Guice) in listeners and it doesn't provide hook on listener creation (TestNG is calling new on listener itself). 
https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/279

But if you run TestNG with code, you may ask an instance to your injection framework and provide it to TestNG.

Comment: How to get from Pico and inject into ITestListener?

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the replies of the [previously linked github issue](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/279) (thanks @juherr) here the **TestNG 7.4.0** answer, without `@Inject` but working nonetheless.

To use the baked in `Guice` dependency injection container from a listener, you need to get the instance of the `Injector` from the suite in this way:

```java
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    final Injector parentInjector = result.getTestContext().getSuite().getParentInjector();
    final YourGuiceModule module = parentInjector.getInstance(YourGuiceModule.class);
    final MyBean myBean = parentInjector.createChildInjector(module).getInstance(MyBean.class);
    
    myBean.logDetails();
}
```

For this to work, you need to make sure that every test running this listener have `YourGuiceModule` and `MyBean` should be provided by that forementioned module.
The exact answer to your question will be possible to solve in version 7.5.0, but still only if you use `Guice`.

Here a utility method i've created in Kotlin to provide any instance:

```kotlin
    private fun <T> ISuite.getInstanceOf(clazz: Class<T>): T =
        with(this.parentInjector) {
            getInstance(YourModule::class.java)
                .let {
                    createChildInjector(it)
                        .getInstance(clazz)
                }
        }
```

**Opinion**: i prefer (and suggest) to have a compile-time check for dependency injection provided objects: In another solution, I've solved this by using `dagger` and by ditching completely the `testng` dependency injection provider.